# Grails REST API created using domain class resource returns not found

Tags: spring, rest, grails, groovy

I am trying to create a REST api for user editing.

I decided to use approach described in documentation:

https://docs.grails.org/3.3.11/guide/REST.html#domainResources (I am using older grailsVersion=3.3.11)

So I went ahead and I created the domain class like this (domain class was created by command grails s2-quickstart com.mastiko.auth User Role)

```
package com.mastiko.auth


import grails.rest.Resource

@Resource(uri = '/api/users', formats=['json'])
class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    String username
    String password
    String mems****ApiUser
    String mems****ApiPassword
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        (UserRole.findAllByUser(this) as List<UserRole>)*.role as Set<Role>
    }

    static constraints = {
        password nullable: false, blank: false, password: true
        username nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }
}
```

My application.groovy looks like this:

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.mastiko.auth.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.mastiko.auth.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.mastiko.auth.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    [pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/dbconsole/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/error',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index.gsp',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/shutdown',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']]
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**',             filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS']
]
```

Also, I added this configuration into application.yml, as I wasnt able to make the spring security rest api plugin work without it

```
plugin:
  springsecurity:
    controllerAnnotations:
      chainMap:
        '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter'
        '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'
```

My UrlMappings.groovy:

```
package mems****eprojects (censored)

class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        delete "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"delete")
        get "/$controller(.$format)?"(action:"index")
        get "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"show")
        post "/$controller(.$format)?"(action:"save")
        put "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"update")
        patch "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"patch")

        "/"(controller: 'application', action:'index')
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to access my api using POST request to http://localhost:8080/api/users, I always get 404 not found response:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1598893213831,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/users"
}
```

I tried a command grails url-mappings-report, and I get a positive result:

```
Dynamic Mappings
 |   GET    | /${controller}(.${format)?            | Action: index                 |
 |   POST   | /${controller}(.${format)?            | Action: save                  |
 |  DELETE  | /${controller}/${id}(.${format)?      | Action: delete                |
 |   GET    | /${controller}/${id}(.${format)?      | Action: show                  |
 |   PUT    | /${controller}/${id}(.${format)?      | Action: update                |
 |  PATCH   | /${controller}/${id}(.${format)?      | Action: patch                 |

Controller: application
 |    *     | /                                     | Action: index                 |

Controller: restOauth
 |    *     | /oauth/access_token                   | Action: accessToken           |
 |    *     | /oauth/${action}/${provider}          | Action: (default action)      |

Controller: user
 |   GET    | /api/users/create                     | Action: create                |
 |   GET    | /api/users/${id}/edit                 | Action: edit                  |
 |   POST   | /api/users                            | Action: save                  |
 |   GET    | /api/users                            | Action: index                 |
 |  DELETE  | /api/users/${id}                      | Action: delete                |
 |  PATCH   | /api/users/${id}                      | Action: patch                 |
 |   PUT    | /api/users/${id}                      | Action: update                |
 |   GET    | /api/users/${id}                      | Action: show                  |
```

I am pretty new into grails and this is my very first application.

I am sorry if some important part of code is missing, I will post it if needed. Can you please help me? I was trying to figure this out for hours now..

//edit 1
I forgot to add my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.2.0"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.2.9"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "mem****eprojects"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"com.moowork.node"
apply plugin:"org.grails.plugins.views-json"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.16.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json-templates"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.M2"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:vue"
    runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
}

bootRun {
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
    addResources = true
    String springProfilesActive = 'spring.profiles.active'
    systemProperty springProfilesActive, System.getProperty(springProfilesActive)
}
```

I added spring-security-rest plugin to be able to authenticate myself from my vuejs frontend using /api/login endpoint. I retrieve the token, and then I am trying to make request to /api/users endpoint with the token in header. So maybe the issue is maybe caused by this plugin

Comment: I have pasted your code into a project and cannot reproduce the behavior you are seeing.  See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/naxmarsresourcemapping.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Hello, thank you very much for trying. I see you have a different UrlMappings (https://github.com/jeffbrown/naxmarsresourcemapping/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/naxmarsresourcemapping/UrlMappings.groovy)

I tried to use your UrlMappings, and now I am getting a server error.

javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'denied' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

Comment: "I see you have a different UrlMappings" - The commit at https://github.com/jeffbrown/naxmarsresourcemapping/commit/b0ac9b70b95e8d62ea1b7476f3e77486afb505c5 uses the same URL mapping you showed above.  That should not cause a 404 and I can't reproduce the 404.  Those mappings won't directly relate to your `@Resource` marked `User` class because you have supplied the `uri` as an annotation attribute.   What is supposed to happen when an unauthenticated request is sent to `/api/users` is a 302, and that is what I am seeing.

Comment: The " Could not resolve view with name 'denied' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'" is a separate issue than the one asked about in the question.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for an explanation. What I forgot to mention here is that I am trying to make this work alongside with the spring security rest plugin

 compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0"
 compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.M2"

I call /api/login, I login with user created in bootstrap, I retrieve a token and then I am using this token to access the /api/users endpoint. So I am wondering whether it is possible that somehow the security rest plugin breaks the behavior for me

Comment: @JeffScottBrown When I make unauthenticated request to /api/users, I get 401 code. When I authenticate myself using token, then I am getting the 404 code

Comment: Are you using the `rest-api` profile?

Comment: Nevermind.  I see now the question has been altered and I see the profile now.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to fix this removing code bellow from application.yml

```
plugin:
  springsecurity:
    controllerAnnotations:
      chainMap:
        '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter'
        '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'
```

and adding code bellow to application.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        //Stateless chain
        [ pattern: '/api/**', filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'],

        //Traditional chain
        //[ pattern: '/**', filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter']
]
```

I am not really sure why I put chainMap in application.yml in the first place.

Thank you for reading this and tryhing to help me